# java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=0, result=-1, data=Intent {

Tags: java, android, android-intent, xmpp, smack

I want to send a file with smack 4 in XMPP and need to open a `fileChooser` but unfortunately i got the error that put in title. i see many errors like this in stack but unfortunately non of them couldn't help me.

this is my fileChooser :

```
private void showFileChooser() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.setType("*/*");
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    try {
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select a File to Upload"),FILE_SELECT_CODE);
    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
        // Potentially direct the user to the Market with a Dialog
    }
}
```

this is my `onActivityResult` :

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    File source = null;
    String filename = null;
    switch (requestCode) {
        case FILE_SELECT_CODE:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                final Uri uri = data.getData();
                try {
                    String src = getPath(ChatActivity.this, uri);
                    source = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + src);
                    filename = uri.getLastPathSegment();
                } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
   //================this is the Smack part of code :
                final FileTransferManager manager = FileTransferManager.getInstanceFor(connection);

// Create the outgoing file transfer
                OutgoingFileTransfer transfer = manager.createOutgoingFileTransfer(user + "/" + roster.getPresenceResource(user));
                // Send the file
                try {
                    transfer.sendFile(source,"Hi");
                } catch (SmackException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
//============Smack part finished
            }
            break;
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

and this is my `getPath` method :

```
public static String getPath(Context context, Uri uri) throws URISyntaxException {

    String path = null;
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA };
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);

    if(cursor == null){
        path = uri.getPath();
    }
    else{
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(projection[0]);
        path = cursor.getString(column_index);
        cursor.close();
    }

    return ((path == null || path.isEmpty()) ? (uri.getPath()) : path);
```

and finally this error in reported :

> 01-14 23:24:09.099 12580-12580/finalproject.ffisher.com.finalproject E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=0, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/125 flg=0x1 }} to activity {finalproject.ffisher.com.finalproject/finalproject.ffisher.com.finalproject.ChatActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not read file

please help me to solve this problem. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your `getPath()` implementation is wrong for most Android devices and users. It will only work for `Uri` values from the `MediaStore`; your `Uri` is not.

Get rid of `getPath()`. Use `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` to get an `InputStream` on the content represented by the `Uri`. Then [use `sendStream()`](https://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/4.1.4/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smackx/filetransfer/OutgoingFileTransfer.html#sendStream%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.lang.String,%20long,%20java.lang.String%29) instead of `sendFile()` with your `OutgoingFileTransfer` object.

Comment: thank you. but would you mind more explain about `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` and how to use them ? please give me a clue. thank u very much